# Why template recognises object as unexpected identifier?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, django-templates

I am trying to populate multiple markers on google maps, using django. From Django views.py I am passing listing name and coordinates to the template, I receive coordinates and can use it as variable in JavaScript. But for some reason, listing name gets error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number". I can't figure it out.

tried to send it as a string, but still got the same.

Template code:

```
var single_listing_coordinates = [];


    // Function retrieves listing names and coordinates from View Class and stores them inside the single_listing_coordinates list,
    // inserts list into hotels array and clears the single_listing_coordinates array, so it is empty for next hotel to be stored.
    {% for coordinate in coordinates %}

       var a = {{coordinate.listing_lat}};
       single_listing_coordinates.push(a);
       var b = {{coordinate.listing_lng}};
       single_listing_coordinates.push(b);
       var c = {{ coordinate.listing_name }};
       single_listing_coordinates.push(c);

       //Lists of coordinates gets pushed to listings array.
       listings.push(single_listing_coordinates);
       single_listing_coordinates = [];

    {% endfor %}
```

views.py code :

```
class ShowMapView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'listing_data/show_maps.html'

def test_func(self, user):
    return (not user.is_anonymous) and (
                user.is_superuser or is_user_host(user) or is_user_cohost(user) or is_user_housekeeper(user))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    listings_id_parameter = self.request.GET['listings_id']
    listing_ids_list = listings_id_parameter.split(",")
    context = {}
    listing_ids_list = [int(x) for x in listing_ids_list]
    all_locations = ABListingData.objects.filter(listing__pk__in=listing_ids_list)
    coordinates_list = []
    for location in all_locations:
        coordinates_dict = {
            "listing_name": location.listing.name,
            "listing_lat": location.lat,
            "listing_lng": location.lng
        }
        coordinates_list.append(coordinates_dict)

    context['coordinates'] = coordinates_list

    return context
```

that's the error I get:

```
       var a = 51.526989;
       single_listing_coordinates.push(a);
       var b = -0.078021;
       single_listing_coordinates.push(b);

       var c = Flat 8;  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

       single_listing_coordinates.push(c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's not valid Javascript. As with Python, you need to wrap strings with quotes.

```
var c = "{{ coordinate.listing_name }}";
```

Note, this would all probably be easier if you sent JSON from the view and parsed it in the JS:

```
context['coordinates'] = json.dumps(coordinates_list)
```

...

```
var listings = JSON.parse("{{ coordinates|safe }}");
```

then you don't need to loop in JS at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for super quick response, if I didn't know that, probably would have struggled for the rest of my life. And I need to have a good look about sending it as JSON. mentioned to my boss but he was strictly against that, because it would make things much slower and complex.

Comment: It really wouldn't, but don't get into an argument with your boss. (Maybe he is thinking that I meant sending the data via Ajax, but that isn't what I was talking about.)

Comment: No no, I mentioned him about it few days ago. Would't include you to my arguments with the boss lol.